# Ubuntu server Iptables rerouting not working properly

Tags: routing, iptables, port, node.js

I am trying to setup a simple node.js express app on ubuntu server. I wanted my app to listen on port :80 but it was throwing errors on startup so i changed it to listen on port :3000 (I don't really understand why it is not working on port 80 but I heard it is not a good practice anyway). I found some post how to do iptables rerouting so i wrote that command

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3000
```

And then I tried to access my server and it worked on my desktop browser (although it takes a while to get response) but when I tried to visit website on my mobile phone it only works when I define port 3000 in address. Also when on my desktop browser I define port :3000 in address bar the response is instant.

Can someone tell me where the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

> And then I tried to access my server and it worked on my desktop browser (although it takes a while to get response) but when I tried to visit website on my mobile phone it only works when I define port 3000 in address. Also when on my desktop browser I define port :3000 in address bar the response is instant.

My first suspicion is that your server has both IPv4 and IPv6, but you added the NAT rule for IPv4 only.

Do it a second time with `ip6tables` to handle IPv6 as well.

> I wanted my app to listen on port :80 but it was throwing errors on startup so i changed it to listen on port :3000 (I don't really understand why it is not working on port 80 but I heard it is not a good practice anyway).

Traditionally, in Unix, ports 1–1023 are restricted to the 'root' user. This was meant as a minor security measure, so that users couldn't e.g. start a fake *telnetd* or other security-sensitive service.

The requirement to start the app as root is why it's "not good practice" – of course, the program doesn't have to continue running as root afterwards, but it's nevertheless additional code that needs to be written with great care.

But if you run Linux and start the app through a *systemd* `.service`, you can avoid the issue in two ways, you can either grant it *specifically* just the permission to use low ports (known as CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE), or you can have systemd itself listen on the port and give the ready-to-use socket to your app (known as socket activation).

(If you don't currently start the app through a .service – well, you should!)